# Can't gift a game to a friend through Battlenet app

Tags: battle.net

I am trying to gift a game to a friend, but when it's asking me to select the friend from the list, only name of 1 friend shows up while I have over 20 friends in my list. If I try to write the name (battletag or real id) manually, it does not let me go to checkout.

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have *some* friends show up, but not others, but you can send the gift to their email address at checkout.